# Mouse control buttons

Tags: control

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way to change the view control with the mouse so that it is similar to Rviz?
Having the scroll and the left button functions switched between both softwares is very confusing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8694/mouse-control-buttons/) by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently Gazebo offers two ways to control the camera view: the one you're using, i.e. "Orbit View control" and the "FPS View control", which works by dragging the mouse's left-button to rotate and the WASD keys to translate the view. You can change between these at the `Camera` menu.

There's currently no way to customize the role of mouse buttons for the view controls. I created a [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1609/add-user-preferences-customization) to add user preferences customization.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2